# WiFi state change

Tags: android

I'm trying to set a boolean value to be true if WiFi is on. I'm fetching the connectivity state through the implementation of broadcast receiver. But, the boolean value is getting set to true more than once. Can you please help me through this?? I want the boolean value to be set to true only when WiFi is connected and set to false only when WiFi is disconnected. Code is as follows:

```
NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            Log.d("wifiRun", "Network available");
            ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo.State wifi = null;
            if (conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).isAvailable())
                wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
            if (wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    //|| wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
                wifiState = true;
                Log.d("wifiRun", "wifiState: " + wifiState);

            } else {
                wifiState = false;
                Log.d("wifiRun", "wifiState: " + wifiState);
            }
        }
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.aws.BatteryUsage.ServiceDefinition">
<intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
     </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look a this method. This will return the network name which the device is connected to. If the device is not connected to any, then it will return "none". It is quite easy to change the String name to boolean isConnected, accordingly to your needs.

```
public String getWifiName(Context context) {
    String ssid = "none";
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState()) == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED) {
        ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
    }
    return ssid;
}
```

This will require the following permission in the **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

It should work. However, if you need more details about this method, [read this](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-tutorial-check-wifi-network/)

Moreover you can try to explore the enums from:

> NetworkInfo.DetailedState

They depict a lot of various states you may find useful.

Comment: Great idea. Should i've to provide any permission in the manifest file??

Comment: oh yes - you're right. I edited post (added the needed permission)

Comment: @JacekMilewski: I'm implementing this technique. Thank you very much. Lastly, should i've to register for supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION in the manifest for this??

Comment: I don't think so. this supplicant would be necessary if you would listen for Android Intents that depicts wifi state changes. If you just want to check current wifi state, the code above is enough. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
  //wifi is enabled
  return true;
 }else{
  return false;
 }
```

refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Comment: false gets returned twice right?? For disabling condition and for disabled condition.